# How to programmatically trigger a click while holding cmd key

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to programmatically trigger a click through JavaScript that also simulates the `cmd` key held down?

For example if I do `document.getElementById("anchor-tag-element").clickWithCmdHeldDown()` the link would open in a new tab.

I also want this to work for non-anchor tags, so `document.getElementById("div-element").clickWithCmdHeldDown()` would have a normal click behavior on the div.

Comment: CMD+Click on anchor tag on macos still opens a new tab

Comment: Not sure how to clarify my question more, I am looking for a way to programmatically do this using JS.

Comment: `foo.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", {metaKey: true}));` doubt it will open up a window, seems like be easier to code something and have it open up a window.

Comment: Despite the already provided answer one of cause could iterate a `NodeList`, queried via `document.querySelectorAll('a[href]')`, and manipulate each link-element by providing a `target="_blank"` as attribute-value pair to it. Or one provides a special `click` event-handling to each link-element which *`preventDefault()`s* each event that occurred without a `metaKey` context but immediately after triggers a custom `click` `MouseEvent ` with `metaKey` context. _**The question is ...** Why does the OP want to manipulate the default behavior of a link?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what the OP wants to achieve one has to implement an own/custom link-like behavior and event handling ...

```js
function triggerCustomMetaKeyClick() {
  document
    .querySelector('p[data-link-like-src]')
    .dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', { metaKey: true }));
}

function handleLinkLikeBehavior(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault(); // one never knows.

  const { currentTarget, metaKey } = evt;
  const {
    linkLikeSrc: href,
    linkLikeTarget: target = '_self',
  } = currentTarget.dataset;

  const isNewWindow =
    (metaKey === true) || (target !== '_self');

  if (href) {
    if (isNewWindow) {
      const windowTarget =
        ((target === '_self') && '_blank') || target;

      console.log('before "allow-popups" permission error ...', {
        href,
        windowTarget,
      });
      window.open(href, windowTarget);
    } else {
      location.href = href;
    }
  }
}

function initializeLinkLikeBehavior(elmNode) {
  elmNode.addEventListener('click', handleLinkLikeBehavior);
}
function initialize() {
  document
    .querySelectorAll('[data-link-like-src]')
    .forEach(initializeLinkLikeBehavior);
  document
    .querySelector('button')
    .addEventListener('click', triggerCustomMetaKeyClick);
}

initialize();
```

```css
a[data-link-like-src] { display: block; }

[data-link-like-src] { margin: 10px 0; color: #00f; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer; }
[data-link-like-src]:hover { color: #f00; }

.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; left: auto!important; right: 0!important; width: 54%!important; }
```

```html
<a name="an-anker-not-a-link"
   data-link-like-src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"
   data-link-like-target="_self"
  >English Wikipedia in same window<br/>via click (or new tab via CMD)</a>

<a name="an-anker-not-a-link"
   data-link-like-src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"
   data-link-like-target="foobar"
  >English Wikipedia in new window/tab<br/>via click</a>

<p data-link-like-src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page">
  English Wikipedia in same window<br/>via click (or new tab via CMD)
</p>

<button>
  trigger custom 'click'-type mouse-event
  <br/>
  with CMD-context on last link-like element
</button>
```